# AWS EC2 Cloud9 debugging Python3 in Docker Container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-cloud9

I've setup a Cloud9 environment using a T2.micro instance and I want to be able to debug python code, however my use case is a little bit unique. I want to use the docker container that gets deployed as a base for execution of my Python code, very similar to InteliJ's docker debugging feature for Python however I end up with an error: `Could not connect debugger to the debugger proxy`. I have the following configuration in my Python3 run file:

```
{
  "script": [
    "if [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
    "    docker run --rm --expose 15471 -p 15471:15471 -v /home/ubuntu/environment/:/project_directory little-test:latest sh -c \"python3 -m ikp3db -ik_p=15471 test.py \"",
    //original"    python3 -m ikp3db -ik_p=15471 -ik_cwd=$project_path \"$file\" $args",
    "else",
    "    docker run --rm -v /home/ubuntu/environment/:/project_directory little-test:latest sh -c \"python3 test.py\"",
    "fi",
    "checkExitCode() {",
    "    if [ $1 ] && [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
    "        python3 -m ikp3db 2>&1 | grep -q 'No module' && echo '",
    "    To use python debugger install ikpdb by running: ",
    "        sudo yum update;",
    "        sudo yum install python36-devel;",
    "        sudo pip-3.6 install ikp3db;",
    "        '",
    "    fi",
    "   return $1",
    "}",
    "checkExitCode $?"
  ],
  "python_version": "python3",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "debugport": 15471,
  "$debugDefaultState": false,
  "debugger": "ikpdb",
  "selector": "^.*\\.(py)$",
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "$python_path"
  },
  "trackId": "Python3"
}
```

However run running a script with this I get a red pop up at the top of the Cloud9 IDE that says: `Could not connect debugger to the debugger proxy`. I thought maybe I got some of the port configuration wrong so I checked `sudo lsof -i -P -n` for both the original and the modified relevant bits are :

original

```
python3   19833          ubuntu    3u  IPv4 201049      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:15471 (LISTEN)
python3   19833          ubuntu    4u  IPv4 201050      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:15471->127.0.0.1:33800 (ESTABLISHED)
```

modified

```
docker-pr 7805            root    4u  IPv4 154992      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:15471 (LISTEN)
```

The only difference seems to be the user it belongs to. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with adding `-ik_a=0.0.0.0` parameter for the ikp3db running within container. If it will attach only on loopback address in container (which is default behaviour) it shouldn't be reachable from outside, independent of published ports.